# How to increase vertical spacing around math, only when needed

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have a very long double spaced document with many math equations. The spacing on the majority work perfectly. However, with some large, matrix equations this occurs:

[image: Working perfectly]

[image: Working beneath the equation]

[image: Not working at all]

As you can see the spacing works some of the time. I can go in and manually add vertical spacing to fix them individually, but is it possible to fix this for the entire document?

```
\setstretch{2} %spacing for text
\lipsum[1]
\[A\vec{u}=\vec{f}\]
\lipsum[2]
\[\vtab
\I(4) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \]
\lipsum[2]
\[ \begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda_1 & \Lambda_{p,1} \\
\Lambda_{m,2} & \Lambda_2 & \ddots \\
&\ddots& \ddots& \Lambda_{p,N_z-1}\\
&&\Lambda_{m,N_z}& \Lambda_{N_z}\\
\end{bmatrix}  =
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
L_2 & 1 \\
&\ddots& \ddots\\
&&L_{N_z}& 1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
U_1 & \Lambda_{p,1} \\
& U_2 & \ddots\\
&& \ddots& \Lambda_{p,N_z-1}\\
&&& U_{N_z}
\end{bmatrix} \]
\lipsum[2]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Apparently I placed the question in the wrong topic, thank you for migrating the question!

Comment: please edit so your example is a complete small document that can reproduce the issue. Note you will get some artifacts from using `\lipsum` here as that ends the paragraph and you should never end a paragraph before display math

Comment: After removin undefined commands your code fragment works fine and doesn't reproduce your problem. So please, extend your code fragment to complete small, compilable document.

Comment: Generally, it is easier to add spacing outside the equation than inside.  Inside equations I use struts (`\rule[...]{0pt}{...}`}.